# Can I use EV from Sectigo for windows driver?

Tags: driver, code-signing, code-signing-certificate

I can not see Sectigo from their recommendation.

https://learn.microsoft.com/zh-cn/windows-hardware/drivers/dashboard/hardware-program-register

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Got replay from the vendor.

```
Thank you for contacting Sectigo Technical support.

Yes, we are also Microsoft partners, our EV code signing certificate can be submitted on Microsoft Windows Hardware Developer Program.

I'm not sure why it was not listed here - EV certificate needs to be purchased

I can assure you that our EV certificate will work on Microsoft Windows Hardware Developer Program.. 

Please let us know if you need any further support.

Helpful Links:
Support Page: sectigo.com/support
Knowledgebase: https://sectigo.com/knowledge-base
System Status: https://sectigo.status.io

Regards,
Logan
SECTIGO - Technical Support Team.
```